# Best way to get data from text (char *)

Tags: c++, tcp, cryptography

Hey,
I'm sending messages via TCP and UDP from clients to the server while the server written in C++. I'm wondering what would be the best, must secure way to send, for example, if I want to send login data: email, password and IP. What would be the best way to send it in a message ang read the data in the server, while this data is stored in char *.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another poster stated, don't worry about C++; use SSL or TLS.  This means you will need to acquire a certificate for the server, and that will cost you between $50 and $1500 dollars if you get a commercial one, or you can make your own from a intranet certificate authority that you establish yourself.

This measure will encrypt the communication, and ensure that your client is actually "talking" to the authentic server, not an imposter.  However, if you need the client to also be authenticated, then you will need a second certificate (possibly one per client machine, to be precise).  If that is too heavy-weight for your client needs, then consider using HMAC to help determine an authorized client from an imposter.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't explained myself correct... I'm after the securitry part, I have a string stored in C++ in the server which is a C++ app andthis string should contain the details, let's say in just a text (it will be encryption, let's assume it;s just a simple text), I wanna ouytpot that string that contains email, password and IP into separated username in one string, password in other string and IP in other string. What would be the best way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you can use a self-signed certificate for free.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't really have anything to do with C++. You are asking a generic question about information security. You want to send information via TCP or UDP that includes sensitive information (email address, password, and IP).  For this you need to use cryptography.

Cryptography is a complicated area where you should not try to roll your own protocols unless you know a lot about what you are doing. Instead, you should avoid UDP (because it is VERY hard to do crypto properly over UDP) and simply use SSL over TCP.

To do this from C++ you can use the OpenSSL sockets library. Both the client and the server link with the library. If you want a little help, you can debug using sslwrap, a command-line tool that allows you to use cleartext sockets from your client & server, but have the unencrypted data wrapped inside an SSL TCP connection.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't explained myself correct... I'm after the securitry part, I have a string stored in C++ in the server which is a C++ app andthis string should contain the details, let's say in just a text (it will be encryption, let's assume it;s just a simple text), I wanna ouytpot that string that contains email, password and IP into separated username in one string, password in other string and IP in other string. What would be the best way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: You've explained yourself great. It's irrevellant that you are using a C++ server. Create a TCP protocol (or use XMLRPC or REST) and run it over SSL.

Comment: Do you mean that you are *not* after the security part, but are asking a question about splitting a string into three fields? If that's the case why did you tag your question with "Cryptography"?